# Laravel - Create or Update by defined attributes

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have this this table:

```
--Votes--
id: Integer
post_id: Integer
user_id: Integer
positive: Boolean
```

Now I would like to create a record only if it not exists. It is working until someone wants to click on dislike after he clicked on like(on the other side exactly equivalent).

For example someone likes a post a record will be created with `positive=true`. Now if the user clicks on the same post but this time on dislike, it will be created another record, but i want that it only updates the existing record.

Is there a simple solution?
Here is my Code to create the record:

```
            $vote = Vote::firstOrCreate(array(
                    'post_id' => $request->input('post_id'),
                    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                    'positive' => $request->input('positive')
            ));
```

**Note**: If someone knows how to do that, maybe he could show me how a deletion would be. For example someone clicks on like two times. The record should be created an deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `updateOrCreate` method:

```
public static function updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = array())
    {
        $instance = static::firstOrNew($attributes);

        $instance->fill($values)->save();

        return $instance;
    }
```

have a look: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L605

EDIT:
Example

```
$attributes = [
    'name' => 'Christian',
    'email' => 'christian@example.com'
];

$values = [
    'name' => 'Christian',
    'email' => 'christian@example.com',
    'phone' => '123456789'
];

MyModel::updateOrCreate($attributes, $values);
```

In the example above I will search if in my table I have an entry which match `name` and `email`, if it exists I will update the records, otherwise I will insert a new entry with the `$values` infos

Comment: ok sounds interessting but i still don't know how to use it correctly. what do i need to pass?

Comment: you need to pass as first param the attributes you need in order to perform the `where` statement, in the second param just need the `values`` you need to update or insert

Comment: Funny. I found it a few seconds ago on myself. Thanks

Comment: I have added an example :)